# How to install specific gnuradio version using PyBombs?

Tags: gnuradio

I would like to install specific gnuradio library release (3.7.10) using PyBombs (https://github.com/gnuradio/pybombs).
I have done following steps:

```
sudo pip install PyBOMBS
pybombs auto-config
pybombs recipes add gr-recipes git+https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-recipes.git
pybombs recipes add gr-etcetera git+https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-etcetera.git
mkdir /home/myuser/gnuradio
```

Now if I run `pybombs prefix init /home/myuser/gnuradio/prefix -a myprefix -R gnuradio-default` it will install the latest gnuradio. How could I install some older releases? I see that in the recipes file `/home/myuser/.pybombs/recipes/gr-recipes/gnuradio.lwr` i could set a branch, but is it possible to set a release tag?

My machine is running Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 4):

Here is the way I installed older tagged release v3.7.11, note the pybombs config command before installing:

```
sudo pip install PyBOMBS
pybombs auto-config
pybombs recipes add gr-recipes git+https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-recipes.git
pybombs recipes add gr-etcetera git+https://github.com/gnuradio/gr-etcetera.git
mkdir /home/myuser/gnuradio
pybombs config --package gnuradio gitrev v3.7.11
pybombs prefix init /home/myuser/gnuradio/prefix -a myprefix -R gnuradio-default
```